# Non-volatile fields + first object access from another thread (java)

Tags: java, multithreading, jls, java-memory-model

I have been working on a certain server-type application for a while now, and I found that its design challenges the way I see memory coherence (so to speak) in Java.

---

This application uses NIO, therefore there is a limited amount of I/O threads (they only do network I/O and nothing else; **they never terminate**, but may get blocked waiting for more work).

Each connection is internally represented as an object of a specific type, let's call it `ClientCon` for the sake of this example. `ClientCon` has various session related fields, none of which are volatile. There is no synchronization of any kind in relation to getting/setting values for these fields.

Received data is made up of logical units with a fixed maximum size. Each such unit has some metadata that allows the handling type (class) to be decided. Once that is done, **a new object** of that type is created. All such handlers have fields, none of which are volatile. An I/O thread (a concrete I/O thread is assigned to each `ClientCon`) then calls a `protected` read method with remaining buffer contents (after metadata was read) on the new handler object.

After this, the same handler object is put into a special queue, which (the queue) is then submitted to a thread pool for execution (where each handler's run method is called to take actions based on the read data). For the sake of this example, we can say that TP threads **never terminate**.

**Therefore, a TP thread will get its hands on an object it never had access to before. All fields of that object are non-volatile** (and most/all are non-final, as they were modified outside the constructor).

The handler's run method may act based on session-specific fields in `ClientCon` as well as set them and/or act on handler object's own fields, whose values were set in the read method.

---

According to CPJ (Concurrent Programming in Java: Design and Principles):

> **The first time a thread accesses a field of an object, it sees either the initial value of the field or a value since written by some other thread.**

A more comprehensive example of this quote can be found in [JLS 17.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5):

```
class FinalFieldExample { 
    final int x;
    int y; 
    static FinalFieldExample f;

    public FinalFieldExample() {
        x = 3; 
        y = 4; 
    } 

    static void writer() {
        f = new FinalFieldExample();
    } 

    static void reader() {
        if (f != null) {
            int i = f.x;  // guaranteed to see 3  
            int j = f.y;  // could see 0
        } 
    } 
}
```

> The class FinalFieldExample has a final int field x and a non-final
>   int field y. One thread might execute the method writer and another
>   might execute the method reader.
>
> **Because the writer method writes f after the object's constructor
>   finishes,** the reader method will be guaranteed to see the properly
>   initialized value for f.x: it will read the value 3. However, **f.y is
>   not final; the reader method is therefore not guaranteed to see the
>   value 4 for it.**

---

This application has been running on x86 (and x86/64) Windows/Unix OSes (Linux flavors, Solaris) for years now (both Sun/Oracle and OpenJDK JVMs, versions 1.5 to 8) and apparently there have been no memory coherency issues related to received data handling. Why?

---

**To sum it up, is there a way for a TP thread to see the object as it was initialized after construction and be unable to see all or some changes done by an I/O thread when it called the `protected` read method?** If so, it would be nice if a detailed example could be presented.

Otherwise, are there some side-effects that could cause the object's field values to **always** be visible in other threads (e.g. I/O thread acquiring a monitor when adding the handler object to a queue)? Neither the I/O thread nor the TP thread synchronizes on the handler object itself. The queue does no such thing as well (not that it would make sense, anyway). Is this related to a concrete JVM's implementation details, perhaps?

---

---

EDIT:

> It follows from the above definitions that:
>
> An unlock on a monitor happens-before every subsequent lock on that
>   monitor. **– Not applicable: monitor is not acquired on the handler object**
>
> A write to a volatile field (§8.3.1.4) happens-before every subsequent
>   read of that field. **– Not applicable: no volatile fields**
>
> A call to start() on a thread happens-before any actions in the
>   started thread. **– A TP thread might already exist when the queue with handler object(s) is submitted for execution. A new handler object might be added to queue amidst an execution on an existing TP thread.**
>
> All actions in a thread happen-before any other thread successfully
>   returns from a join() on that thread. **– Not applicable: threads do not wait for each other**
>
> The default initialization of any object happens-before any other
>   actions (other than default-writes) of a program. **– Not applicable: field writes are after default init AND after constructor finishes**
>
> **When a program contains two conflicting accesses (§17.4.1) that are
>   not ordered by a happens-before relationship, it is said to contain a
>   data race.**

and

> Memory that can be shared between threads is called shared memory or
>   heap memory.
>
> **All instance fields**, static fields, and array elements **are stored in
>   heap memory**. In this chapter, we use the term variable to refer to
>   both fields and array elements.
>
> Local variables (§14.4), formal method parameters (§8.4.1), and
>   exception handler parameters (§14.20) are never shared between threads
>   and are unaffected by the memory model.
>
> **Two accesses to (reads of or writes to) the same variable are said to
>   be conflicting if at least one of the accesses is a write.**

There was a write without forcing a HB relationship on field(s), and later there is a read, once again, not forcing a HB relationship on those field(s). Or am I horribly wrong here? That is, there is no declaration that anything about the object could have changed, so why would the JVM force-flush possibly cached values for these fields?

---

### TL;DR

Thread #1 writes values to a new object's fields in a way that does not allow JVM to know that those values should be propagated to other threads.

Thread #2 acquires the object that was modified after construction by Thread #1 and reads those field values.

Why does the issue described in `FinalFieldExample`/[JLS 17.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5) NEVER happen in practice?

Why does Thread #2 never see only a default-initialized object (or, alternatively, the object as it was after construction, but before/in the mid of field value changes by Thread #1)?

Comment: This sounds like you are asking for the entire java memory model chapter from the Java Concurrency in Practice book.

Comment: Okay, the correct question is: why there are no memory coherence issues in practice in relation to the example design specified?

Comment: because the JVM specs set a lowest common denominator for the visibility you can expect. some JVM implementations take more liberties than others. but this is covered in the JMM chapter.

Comment: To add a bit to what Nathan said, the JVM spec is written for a relaxed memory model (random Google search: http://preshing.com/20120930/weak-vs-strong-memory-models/ ).  Since you're running on Intel, you have rather stronger memory guarantees than what the JLS provides.  Beware if you ever switch CPU hardware though.

Comment: Also: what type of thread pool are you using?  Are you using `ExecutorService` or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might depend on what type of thread pool you are using.  If it's an `ExecutorService`, then that class makes some strong guarantees about its task.  [From the documentation:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

> Memory consistency effects: Actions in a thread prior to the submission of a Runnable or Callable task to an ExecutorService happen-before any actions taken by that task, which in turn happen-before the result is retrieved via Future.get().

So when you initialize any object, plus any other objects, then submit that object to an `ExecutorService`, all those writes are made visible to the thread that will eventually handle your task.

Now, if you home-rolled your own thread pool, or you're using a thread pool with out these guarantees, then all bets are off.  I'd say switch to something that has the guarantee though.

Comment: First of all, the handler object is passed to a custom queue, which uses `ArrayDeque` internally (add synchronizes over this internal deque), then this custom queue is passed to a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with a `SynchronousQueue`. So if I understand correctly, when a thread acquires **any** monitor, non-synchronized inter-thread actions done by that thread so far (JLS 17.4.2) are "committed"?

Comment: @afk5min Not in general.  The writes are only "committed" with respect to another thread that also acquires the same monitor.  It's a odd feature of Java that the memory model is not "global".  Two threads have to synchronize with each other for writes to be guaranteed to be visible.  Note that final fields don't involve synchronization (they use a "freeze-action") and those writes *are* global.

Comment: Yup, I see the point now. The I/O thread will sync on handler object queue and may sync on the thread pool, and the TP thread will sync on the thread pool and will always sync on the handler object queue. So the same monitor will always be acquired and inter-thread actions will become visible to the TP thread.

Answer (score 3):

I'm quite sure that when a thread pool starts a thread / runs a callable, it has a [hapens-before](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happened-before) semantics, so *all changes before the happens-before* are available to the thread.

The scenario you mentioned in CPJ is valid when you have more than one thread modifying data concurrently on the same object instance (e.g. 2 threads already running and modifying the same value (or values that happen to be next to each other in the heap).

It looks like in your case, there is no concurrent modification/read of the fields.

Comment: That is correct. Reads happen long (relatively) after write has completed. However, no monitor is ever acquired on the object that is being modified – despite that it will be accessed by some other thread. If I understand correctly, you would imply "A call to start() on a thread happens-before any actions in the started thread.": but a TP thread might already exist; or the queue might be already executed in a TP thread at the time a new object arrives.

Comment: Some queues do have `hapens-before` semantics, such as the `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`. The `ThreadPoolExecutor` class in java uses a `BlockingQueue` which does have `hapens-before` semantics, plus the code in there is full of other operations that have a `hapens-before` semantics (use of atomic integers, re-entrant locks, etc). I just saw your edit... your code doesn't have any of those operations (like using locks), but the thread pool does, and those operations will run on the individual threads, so the `hapens-before` is guaranteed outside your code (for good reasons)

Comment: In other words, after a thread acquires a monitor (on anything), all non-synchronized inter-thread actions are made visible?

Comment: @afk5min: the key point is the *happens-before* relationship between the writing thread and the reading thread. Leaving a synchronized block happens-before another thread enters a synchronized block using the *same* object monitor. And this relationship is transitive. If a writer thread puts something into a thread-safe queue, all of its writes made before putting happens-before said putting, happens-before another (reading) thread getting that item, happens-before that reading thread performing subsequent reads…

Answer (score 0):

In practice one reason you will never see a violation here is "*most* are non-final" which means that there is at least one final field. The way HotSpot implements the guarantees given by the JLS when final fields are involved is to put a memory barrier at the end of the constructor, thereby granting the non-final fields the same visibility guarantees.

In theory now this is obviously not necessary, which means it depends on how you queue additional work in your thread pool. Generally I cannot imagine any design where there is not some synchronization going on when queueing the work, before it is executed - not only would it make working with this incredibly awkward (for the same reason that starting a thread invokes happens-before behavior), the way to implement such data structures also necessitates some synchronization.

Java's ThreadPoolExecutor.execute() for example does use a `BlockingQueue` internally which already gives you all the visibility and ordering guarantees you'd need.

Comment: I am sorry for such wording. What I meant is that some handlers may have `static final` fields (constants) and/or `final` fields (assigned when constructing the object), but some will have **only** non-final fields, all of which were modified on another thread prior to read.

Comment: @afk5min In which case the part about the ThreadPool needing internal synchronisation still applies.

Comment: @afk5min leaving a synchronized block *happens before* the next thread joining it. Which in this case means that enqueuing the job happens before dequeueing it.